# Set a usercontrol as content to another window's content at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, fullscreen

I have a window that have a user control. This user control has a button which maximize the user control to full screen.

For achieving this I have created a temporary window which I scale to current screen bounds and set it content to the user control.

```
private void OnBtnMaximizeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.btnMaximize.IsChecked == true)
      {
        if (tempfullScreenWindow == null)
        {
          tempfullScreenWindow = new Window();
          tempfullScreenWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
          tempfullScreenWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        }
        var ownerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

        Screen screen = this.GetContainingScreen(ownerWindow);

        tempfullScreenWindow.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
        tempfullScreenWindow.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
        tempfullScreenWindow.Width = screen.Bounds.Width;
        tempfullScreenWindow.Height = screen.Bounds.Height;

        // InvalidOperationException comes here (Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.)
        tempfullScreenWindow.Content = this;  

        tempfullScreenWindow.Owner = ownerWindow;
        tempfullScreenWindow.ShowDialog();
      }
      else
      {
        if (tempfullScreenWindow != null)
        {
          tempfullScreenWindow.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

How can I set the usercontrol as content of the newly created window, by detaching it from owner window and when temp window is closed, re-attach the same to parent window.

Comment: Never worked with WPF, so I don't post this an answer, but Content is read/write. Could you simply say: `this.Content = null;` before the assignment to tempFullScreenWindow?

Comment: Steve this code is inside the usercontrol itself that why i am finding hostingwindow by using ownerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);. And i cannot make the content null as parent window might contains other user controls that might get lost.

Comment: Well, in that case, you could parent your usercontrol to a panel in which it is the only children. Then setting panel.content = null should be harmless. Out of curiosity, I have found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/588456aa-110c-4ad2-baf3-d6b44d8157c0/) discussing a similar problem. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
mywindow.Content = new MyuserControl();
```

Make sure for a control can have only one parent at a time. Detach from first window first and then attach it to other.

Comment: dats what I am trying to find how to detach the instance of usercontrol from OwnerWindow from user control's code

Comment: Created a new instance of user control and copied the datacontext to new instance and shown the new control as child of a new full screen window.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it so complicated?

You just need to switch current host form to the fullscreen mode.

```
public void GoToFullScreen()
{
  this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  this.WindowSate = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: I have two panels in the current host and I just want to maximize the right panel which host the user control. I also have the maximize button in the usercontrol only. Also I want to re-use this control at many other dialogs.

Comment: So you don't need to move control, just create another instance on the other form and send all required data to that instance of control.